# Амортизированная константа

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм, динамические-массивы, сложность

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что означает амортизированная сложность алгоритма, в частности, амортизированная константа?
Это когда для массива операция выполняется не каждый вызов, а только один раз?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите. Берем динамический массив. Сначала из одного элемента.

Добавляем еще один. Удваиваем массив. Итого - одно выделение, один перенос (первого элемента).

Еще добавление - массив становится равен 4 элементам. Выделений - 2. переносов - 3 (теперь переносим 2 элемента, + 1 ранее). Добавление четвертого элемента не требует ни выделения, ни переноса.

Еще добавление. Массив увеличивается до 8 элементов. Теперь в массиве 8 элементов, 3 выделения памяти, 7 переносов элементов. Элементы с 6 по 8 не требуют ни выделения, ни переноса...

...

Теперь у нас 2<sup>n</sup> элементов, n выделений памяти, 2<sup>n</sup>-1 переноса элементов.

Т.е. **в среднем** каждый элемент пришлось переносить 1-2<sup>-n</sup> раз, при больших n - **1** раз.

Константа? Да. При том, что первый элемент переносился log<sub>2</sub>n раз.

А вот в среднем, т.е. **амортизированно** - константа.

Так более-менее понятно?

Comment: Более-менее понятно, но все же
В первом мы, получается выделяем старый элемент и переносим в новый массив? Тогда почему в новом 3 переноса, а не 2, выделено ведь 2?

Comment: А, все, разобрался, спасибо!