# Сложность выполнения операции push_back() в векторе

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, сложность

Пусть имеется простой код:

```
 std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
```

Какая сложность данных операций добавления элементов в конец списка? Соответствует ли она `O(log(N))`? Если нет, то какая она? Просто не понимаю подобных формул сложности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Амортизированное время выполнения этой операции - O(1).

Амортизированное - значит, что отдельные конкретные операции (при перераспределении памяти) могут выполняться и дольше, но в целом N операций выполнятся за время O(N)...

Comment: Так то да, но рaзве метод push_back() не вызывает переаллокацию вектора?

Comment: См. пояснение тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882832/195342

Comment: Нет не вызывает. Вектор - это суть массив. Он будет реаллоцироваться только когда закончится предварительно выделенная память. Примчем по формуле, выделенное*1.5 по моему.

Comment: Но ведь тут не вызывается метод reserve(), а значит вектор только что созданный вернет size() == 0

Comment: Из нового пояснения я все понял. Большое спасибо

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, формула может быть разная.